# Google Charts GeoMap Region Code API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization, geomap

I just recently started using Google Charts to display data on their GeoMaps chart type. While this is a very effective way to display what I want to showcase, what I really need is some form of service where I can use my JSON object and the service will look for the lat long and know the region code so I can dynamically add to my map. Does anyone know of these services that support this functionality or anything close? I would just be passing the lat/long and it would return a geocode to map on the GeoMap Chart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no single API that can do it for you. This has to be done in two steps:

- Using the [Reverse GeoCode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-example) first convert the Lat/Lng into the postal codes.
- Pass these postal codes along with the data you want to display as chart on Google Maps using the regular *google.visualization.arrayToDataTable* function.